# How to highlight selected list item in blazor?

Tags: css, razor, blazor

I have created a simple list in a razor component.it is a simple HTML list with foreach loop.

```
<ul>
           @foreach (var itm in matchingLocations)
           {
            <li>
                <div class="d-flex">

                    <div class="py-2 pr-2">
                        <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt text-glow-1"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="py-2"><span class="sub-title-2">@itm.CodeName</span></div>
                   
                </div>

            </li>

            
            }
       
    </ul>
```

Now I have needed to add the following 2 features to the list

1. when click on one list item, it should be highlighted.
2. if we want to click on another item,while one item is already highlighted, the currently highlighted item should be unhighlighted
   and clicked item should be highlighted.

. how can I do this using blazor? anybody who knows about this, please help me.

Comment: You will need some sort of state management to know if an item has been clicked. The easiest way IMHO is to break this into a subcomponent for each item and use it as a state container for each item.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't clearly understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  Here's a demo page showing one:

```
@page "/"
@foreach (var item in Countries)
{
    <div class="@DivCss(item) p-2" @onclick="() => SetSelect(item)">
        @item.Name
    </div>
}

@code {

    List<Country> Countries = new List<Country>
{
        new Country { Name = "Australia"},
        new Country { Name = "Spain"},
        new Country { Name = "Croatia"}
    };

    List<Country> SelectedCountries = new List<Country>();

    class Country
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    bool IsSelected(Country country)
        => SelectedCountries.Any(item => item == country);

    string DivCss(Country country)
        => IsSelected(country) ? "bg-success text-white" : "bg-light";

    void SetSelect(Country country)
    {
        if (IsSelected(country))
            SelectedCountries.Remove(country);
        else
            SelectedCountries.Add(country);
    }
}
```